# add data into a table w.r.t user id of another table

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have two tables:

1. **USERS** (id primary-key auto-increment, username,email_id, password)
2. **QUESTIONS** (id primary-key auto-increment , type, question, date, time)

if a user named TINA(id 3) logs in and posts a question, her question should be saved in the table QUESTIONS with her respective id i.e 3.
How can this be achieved?

```html
<div id="content">
</br>
<form action="" method="post">
<center> <h3> <font color="green"> Ask a new question:
<select name="type" required>
<option value="" disabled selected> Select the type of question </option>
<option value="technical"> Technical </option>
<option value="entertainment"> Entertainment </option>
<option value="fashion"> Fashion </option>
<option value="food"> Food </option>
<option value="education"> Education </option>
<option value="lifestyle"> Lifestyle </option>
<option value="relationships"> Relationships </option>
<option value="health"> Health </option>
<option value="random"> Random </option>
</select>
</font> </h3>

<textarea rows="3" cols="100" style="resize:none" placeholder="Please type your question here..." name="ques" required></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="POST" name="POST" align="middle">
</center>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['POST']))
{
 $type=$_POST['type'];
 $ques=$_POST['ques'];
 $date = strftime("%B %d, %Y");
 $time = strftime("%r");
    
 $sql="INSERT INTO questions (type,question,date,time) VALUES ('$type', '$ques', '$date', '$time')";
 $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 
   
   if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
   {
 echo "<div class='boxtype'>";
 echo strtoupper($type);
 echo "</div>";
 
 echo "<div class='boxtime'>";
 echo '['.$date.']'.'  '.'['.$time.']';
 echo "</div>";
 
    echo "<div class='box'>";
 echo "<font color='red'>".'<b>'.'<i>'.'<u>';
 echo strtoupper($_SESSION['user']);
 echo '</u>'.'</i>'.'</b>'.'</font>';
 echo ':'.'  '.$ques;
 echo "</div>";
 
 
}
}
```

Comment: you can achieve it through "GOOGLE SEARCH".

Comment: too easy to be answered here.

Comment: Can you show what have you tried so far.. Some code?

Comment: code added in the question. The table USER has a column named 'id' which is the primary key! i want that if a particular user logs in, the question posted by him must be saved in the table QUESTIONS along with his id that is saved in the USERS table.

Comment: @tanishas Please look at my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First modify your `table` `QUESTIONS` . Create a `field` `user_id` to store the `id` of `user` who post question.

When a user say Tina logs in create a `session` during login and store her `id` in a `session` `variable` like `SESSION['user_id'] = your_log_in_user_id`. Now just insert this into QUESTION Table like

```
$user_id = SESSION['user_id'];
$sql="INSERT INTO questions (type,question,date,time,user_id) VALUES ('$type', '$ques', '$date', '$time','$user_id')";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: this was helpful! but the values are not getting stored in the database.

Comment: $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    
 $sql="INSERT INTO questions (id,type,question,date,time) VALUES ('$id','$type', '$ques', '$date', '$time')";
 $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

Comment: then use  `$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_errors($conn));` to see the errors

Comment: hey don't store userid in id column of question table that is primary key of question table you should create  a new field for that because a user can post multiple questions

Comment: when i post another question, my previous qstn is erased. Any idea how to keep the previously asked qstns printed on the screen?

Comment: @tanishas Open multiple windows or tabs in the browser

Answer (score 0):

I'ts very easy one using php session.When the user login into the questions section just save the user id in session.The id is USER table id that is primary key.

```
$_SESSION['ID']=$id;
```

The question is saved into the table based on session id.Just create the column as user_id in the question table.

```
$user_id=$_SESSION['ID'];
$sql="INSERT INTO questions (user_id,type,question,date,time) VALUES ('$user_id','$type', '$ques', '$date', '$time')";
```